# .preventDefault() is not working in conditionals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of a problem. When a form is submitted, I wan't to check some things about it, and if something is wrong, I want to prevent it from submitting and then show an error on the client side. Everything seems to work fine except the form keeps submitting. It even shows the error on client side for a split second before it submits.

```
$('#register').on('submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

var username = $("#register-username"),
    name = $("#register-name"),
    email = $("#register-email"),
    password = $("#register-password"),
    confirmPassword = $("#register-confirmPassword");

checkUsername(function (res) {
    if (res) {
        checkEmail(function (res) {
            if (res) {
                this.submit();
            } else {
                clearErrors();
                email.toggleClass('input-error');
            }
        });
    } else {
        clearErrors();
        username.toggleClass('input-error');
    }
});
});



function checkEmail(callback) {
  $.get("/checkEmail/" + $('#register-email').val(), function (data) {
      if ( data == undefined ) {
        callback(true);
      } else {
        callback(false);
      }
  });
}

function checkUsername (callback) {
  $.get("/checkUsername/" + $('#register-username').val(), function (data) {
    if ( data == undefined ) {
        callback(true);
    } else {
        callback(false);
    }
  });
}

function clearErrors () {
  var arr = [
    $("#register-username"),
    $("#register-name"),
    $("#register-email"),
    $("#register-password"),
    $("#register-confirmPassword")
  ];

  arr.forEach(function(el) {
    el.removeClass('input-error');
  });
}
```

**Update:**
Now I am just confusing myself. checkUsername() returns undefined from my server, I know for a fact, but somehow it is reaching the 'else' statement where checkUsername() is called. I've added the rest of my code. Should clear some  confusion.

Comment: Put your code in question itself. We shouldn't have to go off site just to review what your problem is. questions should be self contained for both current and future readers

Answer (score 5):

The call to `preventDefault` is made from the anonymous callback function you're passing to `checkUsername`. If the anonymous function is called asynchronously, then it's too late to cancel the event.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation on how I should handle the prevention of the submit, then? As you can tell, I can't prevent it from submitting right when it occurs because I eventually need to submit it.

Comment: @Popatop15 You need to call `e.preventDefault()` within the body of the outer function (the one that you passed to `on`). It should only actually submit if it gets all the way into `checkEmail` and passes.

Comment: Can you confirm that the callback function is being called asynchronously? That changes the answer.

Comment: Added my other functions @JackA.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the problem is due to asynchronous code not shown, an  effective way is to use `preventDefault` for the jQuery submit handler and use native submit when all validation passes

Something like:

```
$('#register').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();// prevent jQuery submit

    // after all validation passes
    this.submit();// submit native method won't trigger jQuery handler again

})
```

Comment: @Popatop15 If the callback is indeed asynchronous, then this is what you need to do.

Comment: @JackA. right...sure sounds like it is an asynchronous issue

Comment: this.submit() is not a function;

Comment: if you put that inside one of your other functions then `this` will be different context. Need to pass in reference if that is the case or use `bind()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to return false from validation to stop the current submitting event, and then manually send the post request on success from when the callbacks have successfully returned.

Since the callback is running after the validation has returned from the server then you can actually affect whether a request is made. Where as the other solutions involve trying to change how the original submit event occurs which is no longer in scope since you've already sent requests to the server at this point.

```
$('#register').on('submit', function (e) {

    var username = $("#register-username"),
        name = $("#register-name"),
        email = $("#register-email"),
        password = $("#register-password"),
        confirmPassword = $("#register-confirmPassword");

    checkUsername(function (res) {
        if (res) {
            checkEmail(function (res) {
                if (res) {
                    $.post('{insert form action here}', $(this).serialize());
                } else {
                    clearErrors();
                    email.toggleClass('input-error');
                }
            });
        } else {
            clearErrors();
            username.toggleClass('input-error');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

You'll have to replace the `{insert form action here}`, and `$(this).action` might work in it's place, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It returns validated before the function is even run

Comment: Since you'd have to add a means to wait for the asynchronous calls to finish before returning validated. It does cause the validated to return before the validation functions ever make a request.

What we can do instead is to not use the manual submit and just send the request off with the callbacks. I'll edit this solution to make it so.

Answer (score 0):

So I built off of charlietfl's solution and assigned the native form to a variable, and then submitted it within an anon function.

```
$('#register').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var username = $("#register-username"),
    name = $("#register-name"),
    email = $("#register-email"),
    password = $("#register-password"),
    confirmPassword = $("#register-confirmPassword"),
    form = document.getElementById('register');



  $.get("/checkUsername/" + username.val(), function (data) {
     if (data) {
        clearErrors();
        username.toggleClass('input-error');
     } else {
        $.get("/checkEmail/" + email.val(), function (data) {
            if ( data ) {
                clearErrors();
                email.toggleClass('input-error');
            } else {
                form.submit();
            }
        });
     }
  });
});
```

This works.